# ROR Tut: The text claims creating a User without a name in a before block will throw an exception

Tags: ruby, rspec

Here are the tests:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before { @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com") }
  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }

end
```

which is `Listing 6.5` in section 6.2.1 here:

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#code-user_spec

And the text claims:

> By themselves, these tests aren’t particularly useful, as a User
>   object that doesn’t have (say) a name attribute will throw an
>   exception in the before block.

In the previous section of the tutorial, the author led the reader through some demos in the rails console on creating Users, saving them, and searching for them. In the rails console, User instances could be created without a name attribute.  And when I try changing the before block to this:

```
 before { @user = User.new(email: "user@example.com") }
```

As I expected, the tests are green as far as the eye can see.  Anyone know what the author is talking about?

User migration is as follows:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here we go again...The author seems to be saying that if you had initially created a different User model--one with just an email address--then the before block would throw an exception when you try to give one of those Users a value for a (non-existent) :name attribute.  Therefore, if the before block doesn't throw an exception, then you already know the attributes specified in the before block exist and therefore the respond_to tests are superfluous.  Time to try the rollback command and see if that's true...

Okay, the before block does throw an exception, causing both respond_to tests to fail.

In case anyone is wondering what I did to test the author's assertions:

1) `bundle exec rake db:rollback`
Deletes the table from the db, reversing what the migration file did, but does not delete the migration file.

2) Then I changed the migration file `db/migrate/20140919040051_create_users.rb` to this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      #t.string :name   <---Note the comment at the start of the line.
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

3) `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
Creates a new table in the db, but this time there is no name field/column.

4) `bundle exec rake test:prepare`
5) `bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your interpretation is correct: he is saying that the before block will raise an exception unless the User class defines name and email attributes, so testing the existence of those attributes as he does in the two provided examples is redundant.

Technically speaking, the before block validates that you can *set* the two attributes, while the examples validate that you can *get* the values, so there is some little bit of value there, but I agree with the author that the tests aren't worth much.

I also agree with you that this section of the tutorial could have been written more clearly.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look over my question.  However, I tried what the author claimed, and the before block does not throw an exception--instead I get a failed test.  I amended my question to include that result--but you must have read my question before I completed my tests.

Comment: Whoops. I forgot that I deleted the name attribute when trying to see if the before block would throw an exception: `before { @user = User.new(email: "user@example.com") }`.  When I change that back to: `before { @user = User.new(name: 'Example User', email: "user@example.com") }`, the before block does throw an exception: `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:`.

Comment: **Technically speaking, the before block validates that you can set the two attributes, while the examples validate that you can get the values, so there is some little bit of value there**  But rails creates both setters and getters for all the attributes, so once you know the setter for an attribute works(in the before block), the getter has to work(in the respond_to test), right?

Comment: Yes, that's right: ActiveRecord creates getters and setters for attributes corresponding to each column in the related table. But you can define your own attributes, too -- these are typically used to provide values derived from "real" db-backed attributes, e.g., define `full_name` to return `first_name + last_name` which are real db attributes. So you could for instance define the email attribute yourself with only an `attr_writer` and then the before block would succeed and the example would fail. Testing for this unlikely possibility requires an absurd level of paranoia, IMHO.